# JVM setting versus jmx-connector Security for remote JMX on Glassfish 3 server

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, jmx

I have a default Glassfish 3 installation and I am trying to create a secured JMX connection to this server.

I am familiar with adding JVM arguments like:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8686
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote. authenticate=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/usr/SYNCH/PACKT/3166/Chapters_Code/resources/jmxremote.password
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/usr/SYNCH/PACKT/3166/Chapters_Code/resources/jmxremote.access
```

But I am confused by some blogs I see talking about using

```
asadmin set configs.config.server-config.admin-service.jmx-connector.system.security-enabled=true
```

to alter the  to remove the *security-enabled="false"* property.

So I want to know:

Does removing *security-enabled="false"* entry on the  make Glassfish use the built-in admin authentication provider? If so, how do I turn that security on so I can access JMX securely?
I am just confused as to what the  is suppose to secure against and how to configure more advanced usages.

If the previous question is not correct and/or not possible, then is adding the JVM arguments above the only way to add login security for JMX on glassfish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, when you set a password for the admin user, jmx will require credentials.